# How to set custom icon for beta version

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Recently my brother showed me his invite to beta test an app. This was being done via HockeyApp. Once he installed this version, it had a nice "BETA" stripe on the icon. The App Store version had the original logo. And according to a picture shown by the developer, he had another icon saying "DEV".

I went looking for tutorials on how to do this and came across [this](http://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-beta-dev-and-release-builds/). It works for the dev and App Store part but fails on TestFlight, which shows me the App Store logo. Also, changing the Bundle Identifier causes me not to test my in app purchase (logically). Is there any other way?

Thanks!

**Edit**: I would like a beta app icon for TestFlight via iTunes Connect.

Comment: HI, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to have a different app icon for the people that are currently testing the app via TestFlight.

Comment: Are you using iTunes connect of the web app?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

[How to change your icon at Build Time](http://www.raywenderlich.com/105641/change-app-icon-build-time)

Alternatively if you are using fastlane.io toolchain (which is awesome) look at this blog post:

https://labs.kunstmaan.be/blog/ios-continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-and-fastlane

Both of these will do what you desire

I believe they both require ghostscript and imagemagick which can be installed via `brew`